# Unable to hide cursor in MonoGame under Linux

Tags: xna, mono, monogame

I'm having trouble hiding the mouse cursor in the game window. The following has no effect:

```
IsMouseVisible = true;
IsMouseVisible = false;
```

I'm trying to find a workaround to hiding the cursor. Any suggestions? I believe this is a known OpenTK issue, but has anyone found a way to deal with it?

Comment: Set the cursor image to a completely transparent single pixel?

Comment: I've definitely thought about that, but how do you implement that? I can't use System.Windows.Forms (Linux).

Comment: It was only a suggestion and not a proper answer because I don't actually know how to do it - not used Monogame with Linux. Might get a better answer asking on their forums. Please come back and answer yourself if you do find out how!

Comment: Sure, I'll try IRC as well, I'll answer the question if I find a solution.